# Panda's DataFrame - renaming multiple identical values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, rename

I am having a dataframe as below (**existing**):

[image]

But I want to create a dataframe like this (**desired**):

where the duplicate device names are renamed with an incrementing suffix starting from '.0'to'.N'
and stored in a seperate column 'DeviceName1' or in the same column 'DeviceName'

[image]

Please help me out

Regards,
Mukara